# Pass Latitude and Longitude from controller to view with Googlemaps Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Im trying to get the lat nad lng from a draggable marker from my controller,

My Controller function

```
public function addnew(){

        // Load the library
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        // Load our model
        $this->load->model('Sedes_model', '', TRUE);

        // Initialize the map, passing through any parameters
        $config['center'] = '-17.3718, -66.1615';
        $config['zoom'] = "15";
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
        // Get the co-ordinates from the database using our model
        $sedes = $this->Sedes_model->getCoordanites();
        // Loop through the coordinates we obtained above and add them to the map
        foreach ($sedes as $row) {
            $marker = array();
            $marker['position'] = $row->location;
            $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

        }

        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = '-17.3718, -66.1615';
        $marker['draggable'] = true;
        $marker['ondragend'] = 'alert(\'You just dropped me at: \' + event.latLng.lat() + \', \' + event.latLng.lng());';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);


        // Create the map
        $data = array();
        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

        print_r($data['map']['markers']);


        // Load our view, passing through the map data
        $this->load->view('sedes/add_sede_view', $data);


    }
```

with this i get my map with some markers from my database and also a draggable marker.

im trying to get the lat and lng from the marker to an input value in my view, right now i get the coordinates in the alert box. I think i have to use javascript for this, but i don't really know much of it

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values from a text input (or any form element) to the controller using $this->input->get('input_name'); or $this->input->post('input_name');, depending on the method you are using in your form.

In your controller you should update the $marker['ondraged'] to something like:

```
$marker['ondragend'] = "document.getElementById('position').value = event.latLng.lat() + \', \' + event.latLng.lng() +';";
```

So, for example you have a form with

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('update_data'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="position" name="latlng" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

you can receive the data in your controller's method by

```
public function update_data() {
 // use here the $this->input->post('latlng') as needed
    if($_POST) {
        $data = array(
            "latlng" => $this->input->post('latlng')
        );
        $this->load->view('map', $data);
    }   
}
```

Code not tested, hope it works ;)